# active addClass using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have following HTML:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu" >
    <li class="treeview active">
        <a>Sales</a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu"
            <li>Distributor Wise Sales</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="treeview active">
        <a>Purcahse</a>
        <ul class="treeview-menu"
            <liPurchase Sales</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I want to show `active` class when user click on 'Purchase' or 'Sales'. Ie. when a user clicks on 'Purchase' or 'Sales' then the 'Purchase' link will be active. How could I achieve this using jQuery. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **addclass** in Jquery, only one li tag should have active class at single time.

```
$(".sidebar-menu li").click(function(){
      $(".sidebar-menu li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: how would if i want to active ul class="treeview-menu" also active
Purchase Sales ie if user clicks on Purcahse and then Purchase Sales (also active) how could i achieve this??

Comment: You have to find parent of active tag and assign "active" class to that "ul" tag

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it as below using jQuery.

```
$('.test').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```